# Why can't I create a temporary view in Snowflake through the Snowpark API?

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I am looking to create a temporary view on Snowflake using the Snowpark API (version `1.6.0`). I have created a `DataFrame` and was attempting to use the `createOrReplaceTempView()` function as follows:

```
  // code to create dataframe here
  finalDF.createOrReplaceTempView(outputTableName)
```

When I run this code, I see the following error:

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'temporary VIEW'.
```

On a worksheet within my Snowflake account, I am able to create the same table successfully through raw SQL.

Any ideas why I'm prevented from doing the same through Snowpark?

Comment: Probably because there is no such thing as a temporary view in Snowflake

Comment: @NickW "Probably because there is no such thing as a temporary view in Snowflake" - `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW vw AS SELECT 1 c; -- View VW successfully created.`  It is possible to create TEMPORARY view in Snowflake.

Comment: Looks like Snowflake have a documentation problem, then, as this option is not covered here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html

Comment: @NickW This is documented at [Snowpark](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/scala/working-with-dataframes.html#creating-a-view-from-a-dataframe) part and it's available also on Snowpark API docs.

Comment: Rohan, what is the value of variable **outputTableName**? I just did a quick test from my side using Snowpark 1.6.0 and createOrReplaceTempView works fine for me, I can even see the SQL on the Query History.

Comment: Hey @Sergiu, the `outputTableName` is a `String` structured as the following: `"database"."schema"."table"`. The quotes are included within the string.

Comment: Can you maybe share how **finalDF** is created?

Comment: FYI a case has been raised with Snowflake to get the documentation for the CREATE VIEW 
 statement updated to include the "TEMPORARY" keyword

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, I understood that you are running a stored procedure. By default, if not specified, stored procedure runs on the owner's rights which blocks the creation of temporary objects. So, use the caller's rights by adding **EXECUTE AS CALLER** statement in the stored procedure.

eg:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE sample_proc(
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
...
...
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
```